# Visual studio code editor deleting tabs after delay

Tags: visual-studio-code

Anyone knows how to disable automatic removing tabs on new line after delay? Like you can see on picture below, VS Code deletes tabs on new line everytime when I don't start typing very fast.

Something similar is situation when I'm writing comment, create space and wait for a while. VS Code will delete my last space.

[image]

Comment: have you turned on anything like autosave along with beautify on save ?

Comment: Very good point. It stopped when I was turned off autosave. It means, that functionality of autosave is unusable for me...

Comment: The two in combination is bad idea.. had a similar issue with atom though..:p

Comment: Does changing either of these options help::                                                                                                                                   // Remove trailing auto inserted whitespace
  "editor.trimAutoWhitespace": true,                                                                                                                                                                  


  // When enabled, will trim trailing whitespace when saving a file.
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false,

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by turning off the setting "files.autoSave", (I didn't want that in any case.) or disable your formatting tool. (most likely cause)

My problem was that I had a formatting tool run on save, which was removing excess white space and therefore squashing my tabs during editing. Looks like you have the same problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can affect a delay if you want to use the auto-save feature by setting auto save to afterDelay and setting the delay to your liking

[image]